# Error 500 adding Entity Framework to web.config on asp.net web api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, web-config

In an ASP.net 4.5 Web Api, locally and in production environments is working fine.

I added the Nuget package Entity framework 6.1.3 to the solution. Without adding model. Locally with EF it is working, but when I publish to production, it throws "error 500".

EF add lines to the `web.config`:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

In production, when I remove these lines, it works fine (of course without EF).
I tried adding a model then cause the API throws 500.

Is there any way to use EF in this hosting?

Is a problem in the web.config or in the hosting? The api is in a second level directory of a MVC web app.

pd: The hosting uses Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated.

**More info:**

When i GET from browser http://max-prueba.somee.com/api/Position/41
it response a status 500 and Server Error

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Next step i add line to web config to view description of the error

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

But the response is the same.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details on error?

Comment: **Solved!!** i changed the hosting and it works fine!! The new hosting has an error detail switch, throwing error details to screen although is remoting.It was very usefull.